# Volley de Android se queda anclado en mensaje de error cuando intento hacer una petición sin conexión a internet

Tags: php, android, android-studio, android-volley

Me ocurre algo extraño en una aplicación donde uso [android-volley](/questions/tagged/android-volley) para obtener datos remotos.

En el código yo he controlado que el dispositivo tenga o no una conexión a internet funcional para mostrar los datos y en caso contrario muestro un mensaje de error diciendo que no hay conexión.

El problema es que si yo entro en la Activity que lanza a Volley sin tener conexión a internet me muestra el mensaje de que no hay conexión y así debería ser. Pero si conecto a internet e intento entrar de nuevo a la Activity me sigue mostrando que no hay conexión. Incluso si intento entrar en otra Activity que también lanza una petición Volley a otra URL, sigue apareciendo el mensaje de que no hay conexión. Es como si ese mensaje de quedase de algún modo en caché y la App no es capaz de distinguir que ahora hay conexión.

Si cierro totalmente la App (también quitándola de la apertura en segundo plano) y vuelvo a intentar, el mensaje de no conexión sigue. A veces se resuelve limpiando los datos de la aplicación en la configuración, a veces ni siquiera así funciona y tengo que reiniciar el dispositivo para que el mensaje de error desaparezca.

Este es el código que lanza la petición en una de mis Activity:

```
public void launchVolley() {
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, OL_URL + strFechaHoy, null,
            response -> {
                try {
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    mLiturgia = gson.fromJson(response.getJSONObject("liturgia").toString(), Liturgia.class);
                    showData();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    mTextView.setText(e.getMessage());
                }
            },
            error -> {
                String sError = VolleyErrorHelper.getMessage(error, getApplicationContext());
                mTextView.setText(Utils.fromHtml(sError));
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
    );

    jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            MY_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Y esta es una parte del código en `VolleyErrorHelper`, el mensaje que me muestra cuando no hay conexión es el de `s_ErrorSinConexion:

```
public class VolleyErrorHelper  {
    /**
     * Retorna un mensaje determinado según el tipo de error.
     *
     * @param error
     * @param context
     * @return html
     */

    private static final String s_ErrorSinConexion = CSS_RED_A + "¡ERROR DE CONEXIÓN!" + CSS_RED_Z + BRS + "No estás conectado a internet." + BR +
            "En esta primera etapa de desarrollo la conexión a internet es necesaria para utilizar la aplicación. " +
            "En un futuro, D.M., implementaremos la posiblidad de utilizar la aplicación sin conexión." + BR +
            "Perdona esta pequeña limitación y vuelve a intentarlo cuando tengas conexión a internet.";

    public static String getMessage(Object error, Context context) {
        if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
            return context.getResources().getString(R.string.generic_server_down);
        } else if (isServerProblem(error)) {
            return handleServerError(error, context);
        } else if (isNetworkProblem(error)) {
            return s_ErrorSinConexion;
        }
        return context.getResources().getString(R.string.generic_error);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Revisando el Logcat cuando intento entrar a la Activity veo estos mensajes que hacen referencia a la caché:

```
2021-05-07 09:15:04.896 29463-29463/org.deiverbum.app I/FIAM.Display: Unbinding from activity: activities.OficioActivity
2021-05-07 09:15:04.896 29463-29463/org.deiverbum.app I/FIAM.Headless: Removing display event component
2021-05-07 09:15:04.941 29463-29463/org.deiverbum.app I/FIAM.Display: Binding to activity: activities.BreviarioActivity
2021-05-07 09:15:04.941 29463-29463/org.deiverbum.app I/FIAM.Headless: Setting display event component
2021-05-07 09:15:05.088 29463-932/org.deiverbum.app D/FA: Connected to remote service
2021-05-07 09:15:05.108 29463-29514/org.deiverbum.app D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x720717bc00 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x7225df1f40
2021-05-07 09:15:06.115 29463-29463/org.deiverbum.app I/FIAM.Display: Unbinding from activity: activities.BreviarioActivity
2021-05-07 09:15:06.115 29463-29463/org.deiverbum.app I/FIAM.Headless: Removing display event component
2021-05-07 09:15:06.143 29463-29469/org.deiverbum.app I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=1006KB, data=634KB
2021-05-07 09:15:06.144 29463-29469/org.deiverbum.app I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=1006KB, data=634KB
2021-05-07 09:15:06.144 29463-29469/org.deiverbum.app I/zygote64: Increasing code cache capacity to 3MB
2021-05-07 09:15:06.158 29463-29463/org.deiverbum.app I/FIAM.Display: Binding to activity: activities.OficioActivity
2021-05-07 09:15:06.158 29463-29463/org.deiverbum.app I/FIAM.Headless: Setting display event component
2021-05-07 09:15:11.311 29463-932/org.midominio.app W/ConnectionTracker: Exception thrown while unbinding
```

Comment: ¿Te has fijado en el contenido del mensaje u otra información que lleva la excepción u objeto de error original? Quizás eso pueda arrojar luz sobre cuál es el problema de fondo.

Comment: @jachguate no hay Excepción realmente, son logs de Debug y de Información y al final hace referencia a una Excepción que tiene que ver con otra cosa. Lo extraño es que este aparente "freeze" en el mensaje de error ocurre solo a veces. Hoy mismo por ejemplo desapareció sin más, sin que yo haya hecho nada, en un momento determinado la App empezó a funcionar normalmente. Luego quité la conexión, intenté entrar en una Activity y tuve el mensaje de no conexión, conecté a internet, abrí la Activity y recibí los datos correctos (no se quedó fija como antes con el mensaje de no conexión).

Comment: Comprendo, me refería al objeto `error` que le pasas a `getMessage`. Si no es una excepción, se le podría parecer en cuanto a contener alguna información más detallada de la situación que está ocurriendo que pudiera arrojar, al menos, una pista que abra nuevas líneas de investigación. Lo menciono porque es una técnica que me ha dado resultados en el pasado.

Comment: Ok, entiendo @jachguate me parece una buena idea ver el mensaje de error en sí mismo como indicas, en busca de otras pistas. Lo agrego y veré qué muestra cuando la situación se repita.

Comment: Yo vería otros detalles, como la clase del objeto, ya que podría contener todavía más información que el puro mensaje de error (o puede que no, no se sabrá hasta no verla).